# Unable to create vitual device Server returned HTTP status code 401 [Genymotion]

Tags: genymotion

Failed to Deploy Virtual Device [genymotion]

I have successfully installed genymotion on my laptop(OS: UBUNTU).
Whenever I try to create a virtual device to work with,I get the following error while downloading the required files.

Unable to create virtual device:

Server returned HTTP status code 401

Also tried configuring the proxy in the network tab but was of no use.
Any idea what could be wrong? 
Thanks.